# How do I make python show the entire equation and the results and not just the results only?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, printing, integer

I am making sort of a dice roller for my computer science project where I have to ask the user for the number of dices they want to roll(max 6) and the number of sides the dices have(infinity). I've been trying but my output is not the one the teacher sampled. Can anyone help me out!! Here is the teacher's answer:

[image: Teacher's code]

I've been trying to get the same output as the teacher but my answer comes out a little weird. It seems that my code isn't letting python show the entire equation for example (3+3+5=11) but instead it just shows 11. Does anyone have a solution?
[image: MY CODE]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The data type of range variables are integer so you have to first convert them into string and concate the variables like this

```
import random
range1=random.randint(1,10)
range2=random.randint(1,10)
range3=random.randint(1,10)

res=range1+range2+range3

print(str(range1)+" + "+str(range2)+" + "+str(range3)+" = "+str(res))
```

> Example Output:
> 8 + 10 + 9 = 27

check out more on how to convert integer to string here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-concatenate-string-and-int

Answer (score 0):

You can store rolled dice values in a list and then print those values with plus signs in between (for example map them to `str` and use `join`). Also you could use `for` loop for getting the results of the roll instead of those `if`s.

Example code:

```
from random import randint

n = int(input())
k = int(input())

dices = []
for _ in range(n):
    dices.append(randint(1, k))

print(' + '.join(map(str, dices)), '=', sum(dices))
```

Result:

```
3
6
6 + 1 + 5 = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write `print(2+3)`, you will just have `5`, so you need to write a string with '2', '+' and '3' for example :

```
a = 2
b = 3
print(a+b) # 5
print(a, '+', b) # 2 + 3

# even better :
print(f'{a} + {b} = {a+b}') # 2 + 3 = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to deal with arrays you can use `print("string", end="")`.The value of this parameter is ‘\n’, the new line character. So we can end the print statement with any character.

### Here i give empty string so it is going to be empty

```
from random import randint

diceCount = int(input("How many dice are you rolling (max 6)"))
sideCount = int(input("How many sides do the dice have?"))

sum = 0
for i in range(diceCount):
    randomNum = randint(1, sideCount)
    sum = sum + randomNum
    if i == 0:
        print(f"{str(randomNum)} ",end= '')
    else:
        print(f" + {str(randomNum)}",end='')

print(f" = {sum}")
```